# Dictionary.clear() hangs on execution

Tags: .net, multithreading, dictionary, web-config, filesystemwatcher

I have a *web.config* file, that I want to parse in case of its' changing. For this purpose I use *FileSystemWatcher* and *IDictionary* collection. Here is code of my method:

```
public void ReadCurrentConfiguration()
{
  var settings = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
  lock (_dictMonitor)
  {
    if (_dictionary.Count != 0)
      _dictionary.Clear();

    foreach (var elem in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ConfigurationParameter)).Cast<ConfigurationParameter>())
      _dictionary.Add(elem.ToString(), settings[elem.ToString()]);
  }
}
```

_*dictMonitor* is *Object*, that is used to lock; *ConfigurationParameter* is enum, that is used to define key names. This method is called when *FileSystemWatcher* changing event is raising.
The problem is that program execution halts either on _*dictionary.Clear();* or on *lock(dictMonitor);* with no exeptions. When debugging, manual calling of my method *ReadCurrentConfiguration* executes fine - it cleans the dictionary normally and fills with new values. But in case of event raising it stops. Also, if execution is passed to *clear()* method, debugger shows the following message instead of _*dictionary* value: _*dictionary   Count = Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.* Could anyone suggest why this problem occurs?

Comment: does only this one thread hang, or are there other threads in your app that hang at the same time?

Comment: After this thread hangs, I call my method manually (it means not after event) - it executes normally. This call is executing in new thread, so the main program isn't hanging.

Comment: By the way, after the thread hangs, new events are not raising until I call my method again manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some time later, I understood the cause of the problem - changes to `web.config` makes IIS restart the application, so the implementation above is ridiculous. This is most likely the reason of "hanging" the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something in your loop cause the event to happen again, resulting in infinite loop.

Try something like this:

```
private bool _isExecuting = false;
public void ReadCurrentConfiguration()
{
    if (_isExecuting)
        return;

    _isExecuting = true;
    var settings = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
    //......
    _isExecuting = false;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't _lock(object)_ performs this check?

Comment: Hmm.. what is `_dictionary`? What is contains exactly?

Comment: `_dictionary` is `private IDictionary<String, String> _dictionary;` It contains key-value pairs from web.config file. Each key is received by using `ToString()` to every member of `Enum.GetValues(...)` result (see first post). Each value is string, which is received via `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key]` from web.config file (also in first post).

Comment: Sorry don't have any lead. Try writing to text file (best debug technique I know :)) inside the loop and see how many times it's executed and if you have infinite loop problem.

Comment: I saw results in debugger, there is no infinite loop, it just stacks with no further event raising) Maybe values, that are taken using `AppSettings` are mapped, so dictionary can't even access its' memebers when the file is changed? I don't know. However, thank you for contribution!

Comment: What if you take the `lock()` away?